# Java Netbeans Jlabel Hide and Show

Tags: java, jlabel, netbeans-7

I have a Jframe form and once this form runs i would like some specfeic labels become invisble until the user press on the "Submit button" they become visible.

Assuming that i have 2 JLabels named Label1 and Label2

The idea in my mind would be to go for the constructor of the JFrame class and write

```
Label1.setVisible(false);
Label2.setVisible(false);
```

Then at the `ActionPerformed` function of the Submit button

```
Label1.setVisible(true);
Label2.setVisible(true);
```

But this option does not work and netbeans keeps showing several errors, the question is does my idea is not the proper way to do it or i'm just doing it wrong?

Comment: Your ideea is good, what erros do you get?

Comment: Nevermind i got it fixed after Ahmad's post, thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you put

```
Label1.setVisible(false);
Label2.setVisible(false);
```

after the `initComponents();` method call!
for example if your JFrame name is: NewJFrame you should change constructor with this code:

```
public NewJFrame() {

        initComponents();

        Label1.setVisible(false);
        Label2.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Thanks i was adding it before initComponents(); without noticing that, reordering the code as you mentioned made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing `Label1.setVisible(true);` for example? (Notice the ';' mark)

Or check what errors comes up and post it here.

Comment: Of course i add semi column at the end of my statement sorry i did not write them into my question, but they were written in my code.